# How do I remove a query string from a URL when I set it in a hidden field on a form

Tags: javascript, forms

I am setting up conditional form processing so that a whitepaper download form will send the relevant whitepaper to the user when they submit the form.

The condition that will determine which email with a link gets sent will be the form URL being passed back through in a hidden form field.

Here is a link to the form I am creating: https://secureforms.nextens.nl/TEMPLATE

Currently I can pull through the URL with a query string using this:

```
var input = document.getElementById("field4"); // "field4" is the 'id' of the 
text field
input.value = location.href;
```

As it stands it pulls through the whole query string and sets it on the afore mentioned hidden field so it comes through lie this in the results:

```
https://secureforms.nextens.nl/TEMPLATE?utm_source=source&utm_campaign=campaign&utm_content=content&utm_medium=medium
```

I just want the URL to come through like this:

```
https://secureforms.nextens.nl/TEMPLATE
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead of `location.href`:

```
input.value = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want any query string to appear in the input field you can use something like this -

```
input.value = location.href.split('?')[0]
```